# How to copy all EventListeners from org.zkoss.zul.A

Tags: java, events, anchor, zk

I am confused, because I cannot find any way to copy EventListeners from one Anchor to another.

**I have custom component Btn extends A wich takes A as parameter in constructor**

**I need to:**

- set all EventListeners from A to Btn
- do it without reflection and without creation new List with 46 String items only to do this

**Main problems:**

- Events class is not an Enum thus I cannot iterate over all of 46 event names
- AbstractComponent (parent of A) cannot get me iterable Map of EventListeners

  - it only offer noniterable EventListenerMap object to me
- I tried reflection, but I cannot achieve "onClick", only "ON_CLICK" from declared fields

  ```
  public Btn(A anchor) {
      this(anchor.getLabel());
      this.setHref(anchor.getHref());
      for (String evt : getEventNames()) {
          for (EventListener listener : anchor.getEventListeners(evt)) {
              this.addEventListener(evt, listener);
          }
      }
  }


  public final Set<String> getEventNames() {

      Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

      set.add(Events.ON_AFTER_SIZE);
      set.add(Events.ON_BLUR);
      ...
      ...
      set.add(Events.ON_VISIBILITY_CHANGE);
      set.add(Events.ON_Z_INDEX);

      return set;
  }
  ```

Comment: Btn it's a custom component?

Comment: Yes, it is a custom component based on A

Comment: I don't know if it's your case, but take a look at [this](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Component%20Development%20Essentials/Creating%20a%20simple%20ZK%20Component) if you haven't already

Comment: Ok, seems like I need to be more specific and reformulate my question. I already have custom component, i need only copy EventListeners from A to my Btn (extends A)